# Change color of background according to the size of the font

Tags: php, colors, hex

In PHP file I have variable `$number` that contains information about font size and it works great:

```
echo "<div style='font-size:".$number."'px>  .... "
```

And now I wonder, if this possible to change background of this `div` depending on the size of the font? Default value is white, so it could be `<div style='background-color:#FFFFFF;font-size:10px`for font size 10px. I would like color changes slightly when background font-size is bigger, for example from white through color red, to dark red. How can I do that?

I know it can be done in this way, but I believe it should be easier way than that:

```
if ($number==10) $color="FFFFFF";
elseif ($number==11) $color="FCEFF3";
....
elseif ($number==50) $color="FF004E";
echo "<div style='background-color:#".$color.";font-size:".$number."'px>  .... "
```

But in above example problem is about long size of script, because font size can be from 10 to 50 or even 80, so I thought maybe I can add hex color values ​​to increase them, somehow?

Comment: Using an array to map font sizes to colors would be a little nicer. But it does not remove the ugliness that is setting styles inline. You should use properly named classes, and apply font-size and background to those via CSS.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can just create an associative array of the colors that you want and make the key the font size. Then, you can simply reference the color from whatever `$number` is set to:

```
$number = 11; // Or whatever the font-size is set to
$backgrounds = array(
    10 => "#FFFFFF",
    11 => "#FCEFF3",
    50 => "#FF004E"
);

echo "<div style='background-color: ".$backgrounds[$number]."; font-size: {$number}px;'></div>";
```

Comment: Thanks. It's simple and effective idea.